# Communicaton between android application and a webpage

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, json, ajax

I want to create a mobile app that can send messages and images to a webpage . how can i create  this ? I need real help to complete this project .

Comment: Please do share your work which you have done and ask the problems which you are facing.

Comment: i already have a web server running and a front end for that but now I also wanna create a android application that can communicate to that web server (same) so that there is chat functionality between android application and webpage

Answer (score 0):

You Can check [Google Cloud Messages (GCM)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) API's for same.
It will help you to pass the lightweight messages from the backend server to all the devices whenever there is new data available.

[Here](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/) is example which has implemented GCM to achieve chat functionality between Android and Web Application.